# Pandas groupby and cumulative sum over interval

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like:

```
Name    Values
0   A   1
1   A   2
2   A   3
3   B   1
4   B   2
5   C   3
6   A   2
7   A   6
8   B   8
9   B   3
```

Is it possible to do a groupby and cumulative sum over some interval?

For example if I take cumulative sum at an interval of 3, it will look something like this:

```
Name    Values  cum_sum_interval_3
0   A   1   2.00
1   A   2   2.00
2   A   3   2.00
3   B   1   3.67
4   B   2   3.67
5   C   3   3.00
6   A   2   4.00
7   A   6   4.00
8   B   8   3.67
9   B   3   3.00
```

Here I have done average of 3 values at one (after groupby)

Comment: I don't understand your operation.  Are you grouping by `Name` and then asking for a rolling sum with a window of 3 for each group?

Comment: Not a rolling sum exactly. After groupby, I want an average at intervals of 3. Here in the example, for the first 3 rows, the sum was 6 and average was 2, so for all the 3 rows, 2 is appearing. Similarly, for B, the first 3 occurrences are replaced by 3.67 and last remains the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
df['cum_sum_interval_3'] = df.groupby([df.Name, df.groupby('Name')['Values'].cumcount() // 3])['Values'].transform('mean')
```

Or if you prefer step-by-step:

```
df['name_idx'] = df.groupby('Name')['Values'].cumcount() // 3
df['cum_sum_interval_3'] = df.groupby(['Name', 'name_idx'])['Values'].transform('mean')

result = df.drop('name_idx', axis=1)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
  Name  Values  cum_sum_interval_3
0    A       1            2.000000
1    A       2            2.000000
2    A       3            2.000000
3    B       1            3.666667
4    B       2            3.666667
5    C       3            3.000000
6    A       2            4.000000
7    A       6            4.000000
8    B       8            3.666667
9    B       3            3.000000
```

The statement:

```
df.groupby('Name')['Values'].cumcount() // 3
```

creates groups of approximately size 3 inside each group.

Comment: New column is not encessary, only use `g = df.groupby('Name')['Values'].cumcount() // 3
df['cum_sum_interval_3'] = df.groupby(['Name', g])['Values'].transform('mean')`

Comment: Also `['Values']` is not necessary after grouping. `df.groupby([df.Name, df.groupby('Name').cumcount() // 3]).transform('mean')`  is enough. Nice solution though!